# Create object in a loop C#

Tags: c#, .net, object

I'm new to C# and I'm trying to create an object by looping over a string array:
`indexKeys = ["A", "B", C"]`.

The elements of `indexKeys` are not known in advance.

I have an Object `data`, some of  whose keys are present in `indexKeys`:

```
data = {"A": "string1", "B": "string2", "C": "string3", "D": "string4"}
```

The final object `token` must be a serialized form of:

```
{
  "A": {
    "S": "string1"
  },
  "B": {
    "S": "string2"
  },
  "C": {
    "S": "string3"
  }
}
```

My code below is surely wrong but I'm confused about the data types in C#.

```
    private string getToken(Object data, string[] indexKeys){
        Token token = new Token{};
        foreach(string i in indexKeys){
            token.Add(i: {S: data[i]});
        }
        //return serialized token
    }
```

How can I implement `getToken` to get the desired result?

Comment: Sounds like you need a [Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-5.0)

Comment: @JohnWu Sounds like this is homework.

Comment: @Sorceri Trust me this is not. I have just simplified my question.

Comment: @JohnWu or perhaps a HashSet that can IntersectWith the indexKeys to remove e.g. "D"?

Comment: Please share a [mcve] (if I can't copy and paste it into a console app and run it _without modification_ it isn't yet a [mcve]). Be sure to include **input data in code**. Be sure to be **super explicit about the exact output you want**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Dictionary` like this:

```
 var dataDictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(data);
   
  var response = new Dictionary<string, object>();

   foreach (var item in dataDictionary)
   {
       response.Add(item.Key, new { S = item.Value });
   }

   var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response);
```

Answer (score 0):

When `data` is object and using it directly(with reflection):

```
static string GetToken(object data, IEnumerable<string> indexKeys)
{
    var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    foreach (var key in indexKeys)
    {
        dict.Add(key, new { S = data.GetType().GetProperty(key).GetValue(data, null).ToString() });
    }

    return JsonSerializer.Serialize(dict);
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var indexKeys = new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C" };
    var data = new { A = "string1", B = "string2", C = "string3", D = "string4" };

    var result = GetToken(data, indexKeys);

    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

If you supply `data` as dictionary instead of object:

```
static string GetToken(Dictionary<string, string> data, IEnumerable<string> indexKeys)
{
    var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    foreach (var key in indexKeys)
    {
        dict.Add(key, new { S = data[key] });
    }

    return JsonSerializer.Serialize(dict);
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var indexKeys = new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C" };

    var dataDict = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        {  "A", "string1" },
        {  "B", "string2" },
        {  "C", "string3" },
        {  "D", "string4" }
    };

    var result = GetToken(dataDict, indexKeys);

    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

When `data` is object but without using reflection:

```
static string GetToken(object data, IEnumerable<string> indexKeys)
{
    var dataDict = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(JsonSerializer.Serialize(data));

    var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    foreach (var key in indexKeys)
    {
        dict.Add(key, new { S = dataDict[key] });
    }

    return JsonSerializer.Serialize(dict);
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var indexKeys = new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C" };
    var data = new { A = "string1", B = "string2", C = "string3", D = "string4" };

    var result = GetToken(data, indexKeys);

    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

All of those solutions assume that your `data` object/dictionary **will contain all the keys** from `indexKeys`.